# Checking condition while Exception handling in python

Tags: python, if-statement, exception, conditional-statements

This is part of my code in python. I want to check the error message and if `HTTPError()` then I want to add the host to the file ok.txt. But it doesn't work. what is the problem here?

```
except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print '%-15s\t%15r' % (url.strip(), e)
        if e == 'HTTPError()':
            OK.write('%-15s' % (url.strip()) + '\n')
            OK.flush()
```

When I run whole script the output is something like this:

```
http://a.com        HTTPError()
http://b.com    URLError(timeout('timed out',),)
http://c.com    URLError(timeout('timed out',),)
http://d.com    URLError(error(111, 'Connection refused'),)
http://e.com           200
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check whether or not your error is of type `HTTPError`:

```
except urllib2.URLError as e: # use the "as e" instead of the old style comma delimitation.
    print '%-15s\t%15r' % (url.strip(), e)
    if isinstance(e, HTTPError):
        OK.write('%-15s' % (url.strip()) + '\n')
        OK.flush()
```

Comment: Because `HTTPError()` *calls* the exception class. In effect it creates a new exception object but does not raise it. `HTTPError` is the type, which you can check against.

Comment: Thank you... I am checking your solution